# Restful webservice not able to read the parameters of Angular 5 service call in jersy

Tags: java, angular5, restful-architecture

I am trying to call Restful Webservice from Angular component by passing the parameters from in httpParams and headers, but Jery Restful Webservice is not able to read the username (uname) from request.

**AppTestService in Angular 5**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http"
import { HttpClient } from "selenium-webdriver/http";

@Injectable()
export class AppTestService {
    constructor(@Inject(Http) private proxy: Http){}

    url = "http://localhost:8081/loginangular/webapi/AngularUser/login";
    postGitUser(){        
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this.proxy.post(this.url,{params:{uname: 'rajdharg',paswd: '****'}}, {headers:headers}).subscribe(resp => {
            console.log("response %o , ", resp);
        });
    }
}
```

**pom.xml in RestFul Webservice**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.grajdhar</groupId>
    <artifactId>loginangular</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>loginangular</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>loginangular</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**UserResource.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * @author rajdhagG
 *
 */

@Path("/AngularUser")
public class UserResource {

    UserRepository user = new UserRepository();
    User loginUser = new User();

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("login")
    public User searchUser(@QueryParam("uname") String uname, @QueryParam("paswd") String paswd){
        System.out.println("Logging in the with " + uname + ", " + paswd);
        System.out.println("This = > " + user.getUserDetails(uname, paswd));
        loginUser = user.getUserDetails(uname, paswd);
        if(loginUser.getUname() != "" && loginUser.getPaswd() != ""){
            return loginUser;
        }else {
            loginUser.setUname("Not Present");
            loginUser.setPaswd("Not present");
            return loginUser;
        }
    }
}
```

[Response to Angular Service call with null username and password, event after passing it in the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msqiB.png)

**Output on console of Restful Webservice IDE:**

```
    Fri Apr 06 01:26:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    Logging in the with null, null
    This = > User [uname=, paswd=]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you created service method that consumes requests with `application/json` content, while expecting requests with query parameters which are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content. These two are mismatching. You must make it straight, so you have 2 options:

- Change content type of your request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and change service method definition by removing `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})` annotation.
- Change service method to consume some object of your own, custom class `Credentials` which contains 2 fields: username and password. Make your request to contain serialized `Credentials` object in its body.

One of these two solutions is necessary so service can match request you send with appropriate service method.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @bpawlowski for the suggestion, I tried the first option, but actually the response is same again, while debug found the problem that the parameters not getting packaged into the request, and getting the error as  

**message:"params is not defined"
stack:"ReferenceError: params is not defined↵    at eval (eval at AppGitService.postGitUser (webpack-internal**

**Code Block**

`return this.proxy.post(this.url,{params:new HttpParams().set("uname","rajdharg").set("paswd","*****")}, {headers:headers}).subscribe(resp => {
            console.log("response %o , ", resp);
        });`